# plotting a graph from a 9x1064 table in python

Tags: python, text, plot

I have a text file that contains a table with 9 columns and 1067 rows and I would like to extract the second and sixth columns in order to plot one against the other. 
[This is the first 10 rows of my text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sluTj.png) . I would just like to be able to import the text file into python, and then plot z_spec against z_p.

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy and matplotlib.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.loadtxt(filename, skiprows = 1)
plt.plot(data[:,5], data[:,1])
plt.show()
```